# Сортировка по буквам (казахский алфавит)

Tags: php, сортировка

В обычных сортировках сортируется по алфавиту автоматически. Проблема: у нас не сортируются по алфавиту казахские буквы.

> `аәбвгғдеёжзийкқлмнңоөпрстуұүфхһцчшщъыіьэюя`

Как решать?

Answer (score 1):

Функция [sort](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.sort.php). Всё что вам надо, это настроить нужную локаль:

> SORT_LOCALE_STRING - строковое
> сравнение элементов в зависимости от
> текущей локали. strings, based on the
> current locale. Добавлено в версиях
> PHP 4.4.0 и 5.0.2, используется
> локаль, которая может быть изменена с
> помощью функции setlocale().

**UPD**

Если уж это не подходит или не сработает, но вам надо [usort](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.usort.php).